# Should the questions put on hold be marked on questions list with a color?

Tags: feature-request, design, closed-questions

When browsing on questions that I would like to answer or flag, I now ended up to a question that was put on hold. I had to open the question to realize it was not an eligible one and it was already put on hold. So nothing to do about, basically.

On software design one rule is to avoid clicks. If I look for questions to answer, I normally skip ones marked as green on list because these have an accepted answer already there. For put on hold questions the only indicator is maybe a flappy title, put for being sure there is no need to even flag the question, **I would like to see a yellow color on status (votecount, answer count) box to tell the question is on hold.** That way my moderating and answering double focus would immediatedly go for the next one. Desicion of open or not would be easier.

*(You may discuss the color, light grey is ok, too.)*

Comment: That would be awesome. Especially in the questions with long titles, and you can't see the [On Hold] at the end.

Comment: Also it would make more clear, the question appears 'disabled' for any changes, before it is fixed by user and re-opened. Good feature for new user's point of view, too. They don't try and error answering on-hold ones..

Comment: Nice idea! Perhaps a different colour for 'on hold' vs 'closed'

Comment: Well, red for closed, yellow on hold..

Comment: @awesomebing1 Or, put the `[on hold]` in _front_ of the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a userscript to highlight the votes section and *slighly* fade out closed/on hold questions:

```
$('.question-summary').each(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.summary h3 a').text().indexOf('[on hold]') > -1 || $(this).find('.summary h3 a').text().indexOf('[closed]') > -1) {
        if ($('.cp').length) {
            $(this).find('.cp').css('border', 'blue').css('border-style', 'dotted').css('border-width', 'thin').css('background-color', '#E0E0E0');
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.9');
        } else {
            $(this).find('.votes').css('border', 'blue').css('border-style', 'dotted').css('border-width', 'thin').css('background-color', '#E0E0E0');
            $(this).css('opacity', '0.9');
        }
     }
});
```

You can find it on my [Optional Features userscript](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features).

[image]
[image]

Note: This ***does not*** use the API, so there may be some mistakes if a question's title has the text `[on hold]` or `[closed]` in it (that isn't automatically added) - but I doubt there'll be many of them :)

Answer (score 1):

**No, they shouldn't**. Because there would be confusion:

- yellow background is usually applied to the questions, which tagged with one of your favorite tags, one some sites this color is blue, on other sites it is grey
- red is usually used to show that the post is deleted (not there, in the question list, but in the question itself, but if in the question list red color will mean "closed", I guess it would confuse too).
- Using green and blue will make the question list look like a rainbow, don't want it.
- Greying out wouldn't be a solution; greyed out questions are those which you included in your "ignored tags" (unless you chooses the questions which have your ignored tags to disappear completely)

There could be solutions with coloring vote counts in some way, but this wouldn't be intuitively understandable: how does the fact the question is closed relate to its votes?

Of all the changes to make the closed question more noticeable, **I would agree with**, for example, bolding the word `[closed]`/ `[on hold]`/ `[duplicate]`/ `[migrated]` and/or, perhaps, placing it in front of the question name in the list.

**After all**, if you don't want to see closed questions in your list in order not to waste your time clicking them, just search for [`closed:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=closed%3Ano).

Comment: I've upvoted as I agree in general, although I disagree with the idea of having to manually search with `closed:no` everytime, on every site.