# Highlight unanswerable questions (i.e closed, on-hold, dupe etc)

Tags: feature-request, design, question-lists

### Problem

When looking through the question listings, it's frustrating having read an entire question's title to *then* at the end find "[on-hold]" or "[duplicate]" etc.
And so wasted time reading the title as I won't be looking at the question.

The area (end of title) is often quite busy with the question's snippet text close below, and previous question's user badges/profile image close above.
So it's usually not immediately obvious without glancing over to see if a question is answerable or not (ie not on-hold etc).

I sometimes glance at the right side first, but then that's pointless with the ones which aren't closed/on-hold etc.

### Request

Can we have some sort of unique *highlight* specifically to show when a question is on-hold, dupe etc, and so is not answerable?

Such as on-hold/closed/duped questions have their entire listing all light grey background, or some border, or whatever?

Even the notifications ([on-hold], [duplicate] etc) being a different colour to the title would be a massive improvement and make them stand out.

Actually, the [on-hold], [duplicate] etc being a different colour to the rest of the title would also separate them from *user* text and make them look more like serious sitey-notification-stuff.
A possible double benefit.

### Frequency

It might not be much of a problem on some tag(s), but there are plenty of tags where questions are closed/on-hold quite often, and this issue is frequent.

Spend a day in SO [php] and you'll see the issue.
Programmers site seems to suffer a similar issue, as all the data on the question list page is quite squashed together (not a problem in itself, just worsens the issue I've raised here).

---

<sub><sup>Note: Maybe I'm just getting old, and/or need new glasses.</sup></sub>

### EDIT

My question is different to the proposed dupe because the other question suggests having a yellow notification colour on the left hand side when a question is on-hold/dupe etc.

1. The suggestion in the other question does not solve my issue as then
   I'd have to look left on every question to check if the question is
   answerable or not. This is no better than my having to look right,
   as currently.
2. The proposal in the other question is not ideal because it
   introduces another colour in an area already containing some
   colours. It could get confusing having too many colours there.
3. I have suggested *very* different solution ideas.

Comment: See my answer to [Should the questions put on hold be marked on questions list with a color?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250428/should-the-questions-put-on-hold-be-marked-on-questions-list-with-a-color/250787#250787)

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ That's great, but it will only help the few users who see your answer - I want a site feature which will help everyone :) Also, see my edit above  - I don't like the idea of a colour on the left, as it doesn't really improve the issue as I'd just have to glance left instead of right. My eyes are on the question titles.

Comment: True, but the userscript will have to do till then! I think that an entirely different highlight colour would work, **but**, my current method work just as well I think - you read left-to-right, so the grey is pretty much the first thing you see!